# Unity: Deserializing a mesh creates incomplete mesh?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I am trying to deserialize a mesh, and essentially the result is a jumbled mess of triangles with a lot of data missing. The process is straight forward, I get the byte array, and read in the positions, normals, colors, and set the indices. The exact same byte array in a c++ program renders perfectly but when it gets to unity, it doesn't. I have verified the values of the first 500 elements of the all the buffers to a dead match so I don't think it is the deserializer but rather some detail from Unity that I am missing.

The buffer sizes are:

```
+-------+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| MapID | LENGTH(VertexBuffer) | LENGTH(ColorsBuffer) | LENGTH(NormalsBuffer) | VertexCount |
+-------+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
|     2 |              3252744 |               813186 |               3252744 |      271062 |
+-------+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
```

The mesh deserializer code is:

```
      byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
        if( results.Length > 4 )
        {
            Debug.Log("MeshData length = " + results.Length );

            //First 4 bytes are a packed 32 bit uint of vertex count
            BinaryReader meshBuffer = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(results));
            int numVertices = meshBuffer.ReadInt32();
            Debug.Log("Number of Vertices: " + numVertices );

            if( numVertices > 0 )
            {
                //Create new MeshObject
                GameObject newMesh = new GameObject("Mesh");
                newMesh.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
                newMesh.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();

                //Create mesh
                Mesh downloadedMesh = new Mesh();
                Vector3 [] positions = new Vector3[numVertices];
                Color [] colors = new Color[numVertices];
                Vector3 [] normals = new Vector3[numVertices];
                int [] indices = new int[numVertices];

                //Vertex Positions
                for( int i = 0; i<numVertices; i++ )
                {
                    positions[i].x = meshBuffer.ReadSingle();
                    positions[i].y = meshBuffer.ReadSingle();
                    positions[i].z = meshBuffer.ReadSingle();
                    indices[i] = i;
                }

                //Vertex Colors
                for( int i = 0; i<numVertices; i++ )
                {
                    colors[i].r =  (float)(meshBuffer.ReadByte()/255f);
                    colors[i].g =  (float)(meshBuffer.ReadByte()/255f);
                    colors[i].b =  (float)(meshBuffer.ReadByte()/255f);
                    colors[i].a = 1;
                }

                //Vertex Normals
                for( int i = 0; i<numVertices; i++ )
                {
                    normals[i].x = meshBuffer.ReadSingle();
                    normals[i].y = meshBuffer.ReadSingle();
                    normals[i].z = meshBuffer.ReadSingle();
                }

                downloadedMesh.vertices = positions;
                downloadedMesh.normals = normals;
                downloadedMesh.colors = colors;
                downloadedMesh.triangles = indices;

                newMesh.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = VertexColoringMaterial;
                newMesh.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = downloadedMesh;

                //Attach to scene graph
                newMesh.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("3DRoot").transform;
            }
        }
```

Output:

> MeshData length = 7318678 Number of Vertices: 271062
>
> PositionBufferSize = 271062 * 3 [x,y,z] * sizeof(float) == 3252744
>
> ColorBufferSize = 271062 * 3 [r,g,b] * sizeof(ubyte) == 813186
>
> NormalBufferSize = 271062 * 3 [x,y,z] * sizeof(float) == 3252744
>
> Sum : 7318674 + 4 bytes for the vertex Count
> = 7318678

My C++ Render:
[image]

Unity's Render:
[image]

As a related side note, in OpenGL I can pass the colors, normals, and vertices without the need for indexing through vertex attributes. Is there an equivalent in Unity so that I don't unnecessarily need to blow up ram by creating an unneeded int[numVertices] indexing array ?

Comment: All I can suggest is to try smaller and smaller meshes, until you find a size where smaller and it's fine, but still exhibits the behavior, validate the vertex data (as you already did) and see if you can find something.

Comment: Unity has a vertice limit in meshes, if you want to go above that limit you will need to create multiple meshed.  I believe it is ~65k vertices per mesh

Comment: Ah thanks, this was precisely it, 16 bit max ... ugh